# Issue with the submit on zend framework

Tags: php, css, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework-mvc

i have not see the icon on submit button i do this code in file `.php`:

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit ->setLabel(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Send'))
            ->setDecorators(array(
       array( array( 'inner' => 'HtmlTag' ), array( 'tag' => 'i', 'class' => 'icon-arrow-right' ) ),
       array( array( 'wrapper' => 'HtmlTag' ), array( 'tag' => 'span', 'class' => 'add-on', 'id' => 'login') ),
       array('ViewHelper', array('placement' => 'prepend')),
       'Errors',
       array('FormErrors', array('placement'=>'default')) , 
    ));
```

and the file `.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->element->submit->renderViewHelper(); ?>
```

and it's not work i see just button not icon without the css icon-arrow-right

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Submit element takes it's value (text o button) from `setLabel` and values in `setValue` are ignored.
Also you cannot put HTML ( `<span class="add-on" id="login"><i class="icon-arrow-right" ></i></span>` ) as values for HTML attribute.

Use CSS to style your submit button. You can do it something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/nsU6e/1/

If you REALLY don't want to use simple CSS and want to change markup then you need to use [Decorators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.form.decorators.html). Something like this:

```
$submit->setLabel(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Send'))
       ->setDecorators(array(
           array( array( 'inner' => 'HtmlTag' ), array( 'tag' => 'i', 'class' => 'icon-arrow-right' ) ),
           array( array( 'wrapper' => 'HtmlTag' ), array( 'tag' => 'span', 'class' => 'add-on', 'id' => 'login') ),
           array('ViewHelper', array('placement' => 'prepend')),
           'Errors',
           array('FormErrors', array('placement'=>'default')) , 
        ));
```

Another update:

You can just try:

```
$submit->setLabel(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Send'))
        ->setAttrib('class','add-on')
        ->setAttrib('id','login')
       ->setDecorators(array(
           'ViewHelper',
           array( array( 'inner' => 'HtmlTag' ), array( 'tag' => 'i', 'class' => 'icon-arrow-right', 'placement' => 'append' ) ),
           'Errors',
           array('FormErrors', array('placement'=>'default')) , 
        ));
```

Or even simpler (but require changing CSS):

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
$submit ->setLabel(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Send'))
        ->setAttrib('class','btn_submit');
```

and CSS like this:

```
.btn_submit{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  border: 2px solid lightskyblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #0ca6d9 url('/img/myarrow.png') 95% 50% no-repeat;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: thank you @Volvox ,but i do style in `class="icon-arrow-right"` can you help me please because i blocked

Comment: @user3830722 i added example

Comment: i creat style add-on and icon-arrow but how can add on to `$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
 $submit    ->setLabel(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Send'))
            ->setValue('<span class="add-on" id="login"><i class="icon-arrow-right" ></i></span>')`

Comment: @user3830722 i added example

Comment: i do this `$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit ->setLabel(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Send'))
           ->setDecorators(array(
           array( array( 'inner' => 'HtmlTag' ), array( 'tag' => 'i', 'class' => 'icon-arrow-right' ) ),
           array( array( 'wrapper' => 'HtmlTag' ), array( 'tag' => 'span', 'class' => 'add-on', 'id' => 'login') ),
           array('ViewHelper', array('placement' => 'prepend')),
           'Errors',
           array('FormErrors', array('placement'=>'default')) , 
        ));` but it's see just button

Comment: please see my screenshot here :http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1457114/php/outils/zend/zend-framework/zend_form/placez-icone-bouton-presenter-sous-forme-zend/

Comment: Maybe would be best if you would just make submit button you need in pure HTML+CSS. When its ready and look as it should, paste code here and we will think a way how to convert it to Zend Form

Comment: ,you see my screenshot this code `<span class="add-on" id="login"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></span>` it's done me the icon and i want add this  on submit `'

Comment: @user3830722 last update - if this does not help then you need to make new question and explain it better.